# Probability of the events

Tags: probability, statistics

For the events of $A$ and $B$, probabilites are $\Bbb P(A) = 3/11$ and $\Bbb P(B) = 4/11$. Define the $\Bbb P(A \cap B )$ if:

a) $\Bbb P(A \cup B) = 6/11$.

b) events are indenpendent

I have done a task, and it's following

$$\Bbb P(A \cup B) = \Bbb P(A) + \Bbb P(B) - \Bbb P(A \cap B ) = 1/11\;.$$

However I don't know how to solve b task. I need your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say that $A$ and $B$ are independent is to say that $\Bbb P(A\cap B)=\Bbb P(A)\Bbb P(B)$.

By the way, it’s not correct to write

> $\Bbb P(A\cup B)=\Bbb P(A)+\Bbb P(B)-\Bbb P(A\cap B)=1/11$;

what you mean is that $\Bbb P(A\cup B)=\Bbb P(A)+\Bbb P(B)-\Bbb P(A\cap B)$, so $\Bbb P(A\cap B)=1/11$.

Comment: Aha, so I will have to compute it in the following way, P(A intersection B) = 3/11+4/11 - 12/121 = 77/121 - 12/121 = 65/121!

Comment: @Takarakaka: In part (b) are you supposed to find $\Bbb P(A\cup B)$ or $\Bbb P(A\cap B)$? The wording of the question suggests that you want $\Bbb P(A\cap B)$, which is just $12/121$.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to solve P( A intesection B), but I hurried up and wrote P( A union B)! What I did there was union, so I will fix it out now. Thanks for your help, @Brian M. Scott

Answer (score 0):

Independence means $P(A \cap B)=P(A) P(B)$ but $P(A) P(B)=3 \times 4/121 \approx 0.0991$ and you found $P(A \cap B)=1/11 \approx 0.09091$.  Close but not equal, so not independent. Note the difference between $12/121$ vs $11/121$.

Comment: I see, so this probabilites are not independent.

Comment: You’ve misinterpreted the question, I think: the OP is to determine $\Bbb P(A\cap B)$ in each of two separate settings.

Comment: @Takarakaka: Under the conditions in (a) the probabilities are not independent; in (b) you’re assuming that they **are** independent and using that to determine $\Bbb P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I didn't misprint it, I wrote it correctly, but I now figure out what you are trying to say me! Thank you very much, both of you.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott As I reread the question your interpretation seems right.  The problem is to calculate P(A interesection B) under 2 different scenarios.  In the first case it would be 1/11 and in the second 12/121.  My solution is to the problem are A and B independent if P(A)=3/11, P(B)=4/11 and P(AUB)=6/11.